# How to get active window that is not part of my application?

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

How can I get the Window Title that the user currently have focus on?
I'm making a program that runs with another Window, and if the user does not have focus on that window I find no reason for my program to keep updating.

So how can I determine what window the user have focus on?

I did try to look into

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();
```

but I seems I can only use that if the Window is part of my application which is it not.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for that function? If so, what part was not clear? If not, why not?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check this code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();


[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

private string GetActiveWindowTitle()
{
    const int nChars = 256;
    StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
    IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();

    if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
    {
     return Buff.ToString();
    }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Got it working now, thanks. WIll accept it when I can.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to accept the answer, done it now.

Answer (score 1):

Use  [GetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms633505(v=vs.85).aspx) to retrieve the handle of the focused window and  [GetWindowText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the window title.

```
[ DllImport("user32.dll") ]
static extern int GetForegroundWindow();

[ DllImport("user32.dll") ]
static extern int GetWindowText(int hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);   

static void Main() { 
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(255) ; 
     GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow(), builder, 255) ; 

     Console.WriteLine(builder) ; 
}
```

Comment: For some reason this will the lenght of the builder will be 0.